# Can I travel to Georgia without a visa if I have a single-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, paperwork, visa-free-entry, georgia-country

I looked up at the Georgian website and they weren't being specific whether or not if I can enter Georgia with my single-entry Schengen visa. They only state "valid visa-holder of schengen visa can enter up to 90 days".

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: @Neusser How on Earth is that relevant? Any nationality at all can use a Schengen visa to enter Georgia

Comment: @Coke So what? there are nations who can visit Georgia visa-free.

Comment: @Neusser Out of scope for the question though

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any valid Schengen visa is accepted for entry to Georgia (for 90 days within a 180-day period)

So you can use your single-entry visa.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my travel plan is to Schengen area first, and then go to Georgia later. I know once I get out of Schengen area, my schengen visa will be automatically invalid. So does that mean I can't use that to get to Georgia?

Comment: @Kha I checked the TIMATIC database used by Airlines: any Schengen visa is OK. For Serbia, it says a single-entry visa must be unused, but it doesn't say that for Georgia